# gazebo physics:: member function not found

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was following velodyne control plugin tutorial but as i try to build the velodyne_plugin.cc file get this error:

```
/home/rob/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:42:42: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::JointController’ has no member named ‘SetVelocityPID’
       this->model->GetJointController()->SetVelocityPID(
                                          ^
/home/rob/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc: In member function ‘void gazebo::VelodynePlugin::SetVelocity(const double&)’:
/home/rob/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:71:42: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::JointController’ has no member named ‘SetVelocityTarget’
       this->model->GetJointController()->SetVelocityTarget(
```

When i saw the gazebo::physics::jointcontroller class reference [here](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1JointController.html), i can clearly see that it contatins the member function named

```
SetVelocityTargt SetVelocityPID
```

and others, i have a doubt that because i am using gazebo2.2 which came with ros indigo, this is happening. Do i have to upgrade my gazebo to use all features?
Till this step the code builds without error:

```
 class VelodynePlugin : public ModelPlugin
  {
    public: VelodynePlugin() {}
    public: virtual void Load(physics::ModelPtr _model, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
    {
      std::cerr << "\nThe velodyne plugin is attach to model[" <<
        _model->GetName() << "]\n";

      if(_model->GetJointCount() == 0)
      { std::cerr<<"Invalid joint count, Velodyne plugin not loaded/n"; return; }

      this->model = _model;
      this->joint = _model->GetJoints()[0];
      this->pid = common::PID(0.1,0,0);
    }
    private: physics::ModelPtr model;
    private: physics::JointPtr joint;
    private: common::PID pid;
  };
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14312/gazebo-physics::-member-function-not-found/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That tutorial is known to have a lot of problems. I made a few changes to fix it, but the changes need approvals before they can go on the live site. One of the problems I solved was the one you mention in this question.

If you're willing, you could try the changed tutorials [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/pull-requests/373/fix-intermediate-guided-tutorials/diff) and report any problems you find on the comments section? Instead of using the usual gazebo tutorials website, you can click on the links numbered 1 - 6. If you don't find any problems, you can press the approve button. We need 2 approvals to get it live.

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on 2016-08-31**:
I still get the same error. It shows jointcontroller class has no member function called SetVelocity. until above lines it works fine but as i add other two, error comes. i'm using gazebo2.2.

**Comment by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on 2016-09-01**:
Ok now after i upgraded the gazebo version from 2 to 7 with ros indigo it is working fine with the extra codes mentioned in answer. And i really like this new version, it is working very smoothly than previous one.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-09-01**:
Thanks for looking into it!